# Language per user role, how can I achieve this?

Tags: multisite, user-roles, language

I have a multisite with Buddypress intended for **two languages**. Therefore I have translation files for each language, and this for the theme and for the plugins (nl_NL , fr_FR) in the folders languages_themes and languages_plugins.

Now I have created two user roles, namely **Nl and FR**.

If a user logs in with user role 'NL', the user should see the translated site from nl_NL and if the user logs in with 'FR', it should see fr_FR.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot
Erwin

Comment: What plugin / tool will you use to manage the content transplantations? - WPML, Polylang etc?

Comment: Hi there, I use Loco translate to translate all theme and plugin strings.

Comment: The plugin guides suggest to write a filter on the "locale" hook - https://localise.biz/wordpress/plugin/faqs/language-switch - this will need to be run from a plugin and you could use it to pull back user_meta data - such as the stored language value and define the locale to load WP in.

Comment: Hi,

Apart from Loco, in the meantime I've found this. It does change the language of the theme, but not the plugins yet. I have provided each plugin with a language file with the same extension fr_FR.

How could I also change the text strings of the plugins? https://www.codepile.net/pile/Vlk7PMlW

Comment: What plugins need translating - perhaps some do not come with the required language translations ( stored in po / mo files inside each ) - remember that WP does not enforce any specific language requirements and translation from English is optional and user-lead.

Comment: I'd also suggest adding you code to your question, so that others can see more directly what you have done so far.